Error al cargar imagenes en flutter al ejecutarse en un emulador de android
Buenas comunidad tengo el siguiente problema estoy intentando compilar mi aplicación con las imágenes sin embargo cuando la ejecuto en el navegador desde vscode me aparecen todas las imágenes pero si la ejecuto desde mi emulador de Android no me aparecen

lo raro ahora es que me aparece la imagen del inicio pero las de las pantallas me salen como si no estuvieran cargadas

les incluyo lo que me arroja el debug y el problema como tal , muchas gracias por la ayuda

Busca en tu pubspec.yaml que tus rutas estén correctas y también en donde solicitas tu imagen, ay que podría ser un error de escritura

Por favor busque en su archivo pubspec.yaml  para revisar si las rutas son correctas, por ejemplo
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/


Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

creo que estás exponiendo un archivo en específico. Para tener acceso a todos los archivos de una carpeta, usa esta configuración:
flutter:
 uses-material-design: true

 assets:
   - assets/images/

Para incluir solo un archivo específico:
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/archivo_especifico.png  

